# Decapsulate VXLAN packats from AWS VPC mirroring

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc

I am using the AWS vpc traffic mirroring with the intention of duplicating my traffic from a legacy system to a new system thus creating real life ingress on the new system.

the target machine receives the replicated traffic wrapped with VXLAN headers that my application can not read (and shouldn't read)

is there a simple way to install some service on the target machine that will decapsulate the vxlan packets and forward the data to my application?

thank you

Comment: Hi, I'm going through the same thing. Were you able to figure it out? Thanks